Extracting string from ann email body
I'm using python to extract the information provided from the body of an email using imap.
Part of the email that interests to my code:
"BOT ID: 4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964"
I can extract the exact string from the email body with
    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
        import re
        ID_pattern = r"BOT ID: (\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)"
        machine_id = re.findall(ID_pattern, body)
        print(machine_id)

But it returns:
"[('4824CF8B', '2986', '11EC', '80F0', '84A93851B964')]"
How can I manipulate this turple/list to keep que original pattern:
xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Thank u all guys.
import re
ID_pattern = r"BOT ID: (\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)"
machine_id = re.findall(ID_pattern, body)
print(machine_id)

result:
[('4824CF8B', '2986', '11EC', '80F0', '84A93851B964')]
Expected:
4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964

But why you separate each part in regular expression, if you don't want to separate them in the result? Why not r"BOT ID: (\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)"?

using re.findall returns all the capture group values in a list, and you have 5 capture groups

Use [\w\-] to denote word-constituting character or dash, that is
import re
text = "foo BOT ID: 4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964 bar"
for found in re.findall(r"BOT ID: ([\w\-]+)", text):
    print(found)

gives output
4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964


Just use join to join all elements into a string
result = [('4824CF8B', '2986', '11EC', '80F0', '84A93851B964')]

result_string = "-".join(result[0])

'4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964'

Now, in the example you posted the list contains only one tuple, if you want a more general solution where result have more tuples, then the result cannot be a string, but needs to be a list of strings. Just iterate them in a comprehension list.
result = [('4824CF8B', '2986', '11EC', '80F0', '84A93851B964'),
          ('4824CF8B', '2986', '11EC', '80F0', '84A93851B964'),
          ('4824CF8B', '2986', '11EC', '80F0', '84A93851B964')]

result_list_of_strings = ["-".join(i) for i in result]

['4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964'
'4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964'
'4824CF8B-2986-11EC-80F0-84A93851B964']

